# Add wrapper to widgets only in a specific zone

Tags: orchardcms

I'm adding a custom wrapper to widgets in placement.info like this:

```
<Match ContentType="Widget">
   <Place Parts_Common_Body="Content:5;Wrapper=Wrapper_AsideWidget" />
</Match>
```

This works just fine, but I need to to limit the application of the custom wrapper to only widgets in a few specific zones. Right now they're being applied to widgets in all zones. What's the best way to achieve this? It would be perfect if the Match element could be scoped to a zone but I don't think that's possible.

Any advice or suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Here's the final solution I came up with. It applies the custom wrapper to any widgets in the aside zones. Just dropped the class into the theme.

```
public class AsideWidgetShapeProvider : IShapeTableProvider
{
    public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Describe("Widget")
            .OnDisplaying(displaying =>
            {
                var shape = displaying.Shape;
                ContentItem contentItem = shape.ContentItem;
                if (contentItem != null)
                {
                    var zoneName = contentItem.As<WidgetPart>().Zone;
                    if (zoneName == "AsideFirst" || zoneName == "AsideSecond")
                    {
                        shape.Metadata.Wrappers.Add("Wrapper_AsideWidget");
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Shape Table Provider that describes the behavior of the `Parts_Common_Body` shape and applies your wrapper conditionally.  Just add a class such as the following to your module, and Orchard will process it when it builds the shape table.

Example:

```
using Orchard.ContentManagement;
using Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors;
using Orchard.Widgets.Models;

namespace MyModule {
    public class ShapeTable : IShapeTableProvider {
        public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder) {
            builder.Describe("Parts_Common_Body")
                .OnDisplaying(ctx => {
                    var shape = ctx.Shape;
                    // Parts_Common_Body has a ContentPart property, so you can
                    // do this to get at the content item.
                    var contentItem = ((IContent)shape.ContentPart).ContentItem;
                    if (contentItem.ContentType == "Widget") { // content type to check for
                        var widgetPart = contentItem.As<WidgetPart>();
                        if (widgetPart.Zone == "AsideFirst") { // zone to check for
                            // Condition is met, let's add the wrapper.
                            ctx.ShapeMetadata.Wrappers.Add("Wrapper_AsideWidget");
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Katsuyuki! That pointed me in the right direction. I also found this [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/01/10/orchard-shapeshifting.aspx) helpful. I updated my question with my final solution.